# I keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am getting this error for TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.  I have looked at other posts but have still not been able to figure it out. I also did the pretty much same thing 3 lines before this so i dont know why it is not working.

```py
from WordList import WordleList
length=len(WordleList)
#change for whatever position a letter is in
#if letter is yellow, set pos to 0
letter1="a"
pos1="/"
letter2="r"
pos2="/"
letter3="o"
pos3="/"
letter4="l"
pos4="/"
char=0
notLetters=["z","d","r","b","x","n","m"]
Llength = len(notLetters)
words=0
for i in range(length):
    word=WordleList[i]
    valid=1
    for h in range(Llength):
        letter=Llength[h]
        if letter in word:
            valid=0
    if pos1=="/":
        if letter1 in word:
            char+=1
    else:
        if letter1 in word:
            lPos=word.find(letter1)
            lPos+=1
    if lPos==pos1:
        char+=1
```

Full error:line 21, in module
letter=Llength[h]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Would you be able to a [mini code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: What's going on here is simple.  You set `Llength` to an integer value, the length of the `notLetters` list.  Then you treat `Llength` like it's a list, trying to grab an item from it at a particular position, whatever value `h` has at the time.  Since you're trying to access an `int` object as though it is a list, you're getting an error saying exactly that.    I'm guessing that you mean to be looking up a value in `notLetters`, but it's kinda hard to tell.

Comment: you don't use `h` so use `for letter in notLetters`

Comment: `if letter is yellow` when is a letter yellow, use a different theme and it is red

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are defining Llength as `Llength = len(notLetters)` this makes it an integer. Then on line 17 you are assigning letter as `letter=Llength[h]`, This is making the error becuase while Llength is an integer, you are treating it like a list. Do you mean to do `letter=WordleList[h]` since you said it worked 3 lines before?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @GregJ.  Please don't take something that an experienced SO member chose to put in a comment, and say pretty much the same thing as an answer.  There's a reason I didn't post my comment as an answer.  It doesn't provide any useful information to anyone but possibly the OP.  SO isn't about helping people to debug their trivially simple code.  Rather, SO is about building a database of generally useful questions and answers.  This question, and so your your answer too, has no value whatsoever.  Please help us to keep SO high quality by deleting this answer.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help after reading the suggestions i figured out that i wanted to put   letter=notLetters[h]   instead of   letter=Llength[h].  Sorry for this i am just a beginner in python.